# How do i allow multiple value input in a single cellmysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i have 2 sql tables something like the one shown below. how do i allow multiple values input into the category id cell in table 2? currently it only allows single value input (like table 2 row 1) and it throws an error (truncated value) when input 2 values separated using comma. thanks!

Table 1

| category id | category name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fried food |
| 2 | vegetables |
| 3 | protein |

Table 2

| food id | food name | category id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | brocolli | 2 |
| 2 | fried chicken | 1, 3 |

Comment: Storing csv data is never a good idea consider a junction table instead.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon my data is stored in a mysql table and not csv table. I was wondering if many to many tables would work?

Comment: Put another way don't store like 1,2 (ie csv data) in any table

Comment: *it throws an error (truncated value) when input 2 values separated using comma* I think it's because of numeric column datatype which cannot store CSV (string-type) value. Create additional adjacency table instead of single `category id` column.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is "you don't". There isn't a multi-link single table element that does what you're looking for here.

Instead, you have a third table, that links the two. Perhaps "category_membership" It would have three columns: id,foodId,categoryId

1, 1, 2 (links broccoli to vegetables)

2, 2, 1 (links chicken to fried food)

3, 2, 3 (links chicken to protein)

(You would also be dropping the column "category id" from your food table, as this linking table handles that.)